# Difference between application of series and parallel (grounded) capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, dc, noise, signal

I wanted to understand the difference of the two applications shown in the picture below, one is in parallel (grounded) which, as far as I know, is used as a bypass capacitor used to remove the high frequency noise and redirect it to ground.

Would the series capacitor application be to remove a DC bias from the signal?

**bonus question, what do the inductances do?

[image: Schematics]

Comment: together, the inductors and capacitors form some filters

Answer (score 3):

So what you ask must be thought with the context that it is an RF device, such as RF amplifier.

Yes, the capacitor in series is used to block DC and pass RF only. This lets the chip input to bias itself to a valid DC bias point to allow the input to receive the RF.

The inductaces also block RF, but lets DC bias currents to pass and to bias the chip pins to correct DC voltage, and the RF just rides on top of DC. And the inductors and capacitors are just LC filters to prevent RF from passing to power supply node and other componets.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly surmise, C1 and C2 are there to block DC on the input and output sides respectively.

L2 and L3 form the "top halves" of voltage dividers, where the "bottom halves" consist of active elements within the amplifier. They essentially play the same role as that played by the collector resistors in an audio frequency common emitter amplifier. They differ from the collector resistors in an AF amplifier in that the impedance they present to the radio frequency signal is different from the impedance they present to the "quiescent" current through the amplifier. The use of inductors in this way is common practice in radio frequency (RF) amplifiers, especially at higher frequencies.

Capacitors C3 and C4 serve to decouple the amplifier from the power supply. Without them, changes in the current through L2 and L3 would cause volage fluctuations in the ground and Vcc. If the current supplied by C3 and C4 closely matches the current drawn through L2 and L3, then the whole circuit will appear as a resonant *tank* from the point of view of the power supply. A resonant tank minimizes the current at the resonant frequency external to the tank relative to the current flowing within the tank.